# creating objects in xtext

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, xtend

I started to work with xtext to create domain specific language. I succeeded in creating a complex type. But I would love to modify it in such a way that I can create instances from the complex type just like with classes and structs from c++.

```
Annotation:
{Annotation}
'@' value=STRING
;

ComplexTypeDef:
{ComplexTypeDef}
(annotations+=Annotation)*
(abstract?='abstract')? 'def' name=ID ('extends' superType=[ComplexTypeDef])? '{'
    (fields+=Field)*
'}'
;
Field:
(annotations+=Annotation)* (unique?='unique')? type=Type name=ID (optional?='optional')? ';' (documentation=(ML_DOCUMENTATION|SL_DOCUMENTATION))?;
```

I would like to be able to create an instance of the complex type like so

```
def Person {
var name: string; 
var age: int;
}

Person firstPerson;
firstPerson.name = "Unah Henry";
firstPerson.int = 26;
```

Comment: the thing you are search for is "scoping". you already have cross references for the extends so it should no be a problem to use them for a.b and implement scoping for a and b. besides that your question is a bit "general"

Comment: Please do you have examples that can help me understand scoping. I tried reading about it online but I still can get it

Comment: Please share your grammar change and what you have tried

Comment: http://pasted.co/5259c84f

Comment: and the scoping your tried?

Comment: class MuslangScopeProvider extends AbstractMuslangScopeProvider {
 
 def thescope(FieldSelection sel, EReference r) {
  var parentScope = IScope::NULLSCOPE
  val type = sel.receiver.typeFor
  
  if (type == null || type.isPrimitive)
   return parentScope
  
  for (c : type.classHierarchyWithObject.reverseView) {
   parentScope = Scopes::scopeFor(
    c.selectMembers(sel), 
    parentScope
   )
  }
  Scopes::scopeFor(type.selectMembers(sel), parentScope)
 }
 
 def selectMembers(ComplexTypeDef type) {
    type.fields
 }
}

Comment: http://pasted.co/876f0512

Answer (score 0):

your scoping makes no sense. one would expect something like

```
class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractMyDslScopeProvider {

    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (reference == MyDslPackage.Literals.FIELD_SELECTION__FIELD) {
            if (context instanceof FieldSelection) {
                val rec = context.receiver
                val fields = <Field>newArrayList
                // TODO have a look at rec and calculate the visible fields from that
                return Scopes.scopeFor(fields)
            }
        }
        // TODO more else ifs for other places
        super.getScope(context, reference)
    }

}
```

when throwing your grammar to trash and start over with this one:

```
Model:
  declarations+=Declaration*
  assignments+=Assignment*;

Declaration:
    "def" name=ID "{"
        (fields+=Feature ("," fields+=Feature)*)?
    "}"
;  

Feature: type=Type name=ID;

Type: SimpleTypeDecl | DeclarationRef;

SimpleTypeDecl: type=SimpleType;

enum SimpleType:
    int | string | boolean
;

Assignment:
    assignee=DotExpression "=" value=Literal
;

DotExpression returns Ref:
    DeclarationRef ({DotExpression.ref=current}  "." tail=[Feature])*
;

DeclarationRef returns Ref:
    {DeclarationRef} declaration=[Declaration]
;

Literal: StringLiteral | IntLiteral | BooleanLiteral;
BooleanLiteral: value?="true" | {BooleanLiteral}"false";
IntLiteral: value=INT;
StringLiteral: value=ID | value=STRING;
```

the scoping could look like

```
class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractMyDslScopeProvider {

    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (reference == MyDslPackage.Literals.DOT_EXPRESSION__TAIL) {
            if (context instanceof DotExpression) {
                val ref = context.ref
                if (ref instanceof DeclarationRef) {
                    return Scopes.scopeFor(ref.declaration.fields)
                } else if (ref instanceof DotExpression) {
                    val feature = ref.tail
                    if (feature.type instanceof DeclarationRef) {
                        return Scopes.scopeFor((feature.type as DeclarationRef).declaration.fields)
                    }
                }
            }
            return IScope.NULLSCOPE
        }
        super.getScope(context, reference)
    }

}
```

and parse+scope models like

```
        def alpha { int a, int b}
        def beta {alpha ax}
        alpha.a = something
        alpha.b = something 
        beta.ax.a = something
```

Comment: Hi Thanks!! I get error when I try to use this FieldSelection. I tried importing it but it didn't work. Same thing happens too with FIELD_SELECTION__FIELD. Please how can I fix this?

Comment: then you did share the wrong grammar. (or incomplete)

Comment: I was trying to follow first the examples from here https://github.com/LorenzoBettini/packtpub-xtext-book-examples

Comment: No that is the grammar I am using

Comment: yes but it was incomplete: so did you find the YourdslPackage interface? does it have a Literals inner interface? there should be FIELD_SELECTION__FIELD with your grammar. your grammar has `{FieldSelection.receiver=current} '.' field=[Field]` which will produce a type `FieldSelection`

Comment: are you sure you did not forget to rerun the workflow. this grammar gives me a `FieldSelection` type and a Literals interface with `EReference FIELD_SELECTION__FIELD = eINSTANCE.getFieldSelection_Field();`

Comment: Please can you also give an idea on how I can calculate the visible fields from rec

Comment: rec might be an instance of a subtype of expression e.g. a FieldSelection (for a.b.c) or a TerminalExpression for a.b e.g. a SymbolRef which you may ask for its symbol which you may ask for its type which you may ask for its fields

Comment: please help. I still cant figure out how I can calculate the visible fields from rec. Can you give an example please

Comment: I can’t follow you what did you try so far. If you have a.b and you scope b the rec is a. You are the one who can tell me how to get all fields from a. So please provide me with that information

Comment: def alpa { int a, int b}  alpha.a = something  alpha.b = something

Comment: I want to be able to do something like this in my grammar

Comment: No how does the ast for that look like. You should be able to see what a ist an instanced in the debugger

Comment: Is the a question about grammar or about scoping

Comment: I tried with just the grammar and I couldn't follow and you suggested scoping which I still don't understand very well. Any grammar that can work for the example output I gave would be appreciated

Comment: Again does your grammar parse your stuff or doesn’t it

Comment: It doesnt parse it. I get errors when I use the dot seperator